# Mysql will not install due to mariadb install but mariadb is not installed

Tags: mysql, centos, mariadb

Been trying for hours to get mysql installed but it failed due to a conflict.

This is a brand newly installed CentOS 8 x64 (latest) and it's fully updated. There are no custom packages installed this is a minimal install.

This is on a relatively powerful dedicated server with nothing else on it.

I first ran into the issue trying to install CentOS Web Panel. That is the only thing I've done on this server after install and update. The failure of centos web panel was simply the same conflict I'm running into with mysql. Mysql failed because it says mariadb is installed. But even when I removed mariadb still it gave the same issue.

Same issue happens when I try to install mysql directly which is what this question is about. I am able to install mariadb with no problem though and even remove it as well. But still after installing and removing mariadb mysql still refuses due to nonexistent conflict.

```
# rpm -q centos-release
centos-release-8.0-0.1905.0.9.el8..x86_64               

# yum update -y
Last metadata expiration check: 0:14:30 ago on Sat 23 Nov 2019 02:12:39 PM EST.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

Here is what happens when I try to install

```
# yum install mysql -y
CentOS Web Panel repo for Linux 7 - .x86_64                10 kB/s | 2.9 kB 00:00
CentOS-8 - AppStream3.1 kB/s | 4.3 kB 00:01
CentOS-8 - Base 2.9 kB/s | 3.9 kB 00:01
CentOS-8 - Extras   4.3 kB/s | 1.5 kB 00:00
Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - .x86_64                15 kB/s |  19 kB 00:01
MariaDB 2.6 kB/s | 2.9 kB 00:01
Dependencies resolved.
================================================================================
 Package ArchVersion   Repository  Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 mysql   .x86_64                  8.0.17-3.module_el8.0.0+181+899d6349  AppStream   11 M
Installing dependencies:
 mysql-common.x86_64                  8.0.17-3.module_el8.0.0+181+899d6349  AppStream  143 k
 MariaDB-common  .x86_64                  10.1.43-1.el7.centos  mariadb 68 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install  3 Packages

Total download size: 11 M
Installed size: 68 M
Downloading Packages:
(1/3): mysql-common-8.0.17-3.module_el8.0.0+181 1.3 MB/s | 143 kB 00:00
(2/3): MariaDB-common-10.1.43-1.el7.centos.x86_ 233 kB/s |  68 kB 00:00
(3/3): mysql-8.0.17-3.module_el8.0.0+181+899d63 9.8 MB/s |  11 MB 00:01
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total   7.6 MB/s |  11 MB 00:01
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction.
You can remove cached packages by executing 'dnf clean packages'.
Error: Transaction check error:
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml conflicts between attempted installs of mysql-common-8.0.17-3.module_el8.0.0+181+899d6349..x86_64 and MariaDB-common-10.1.43-1.el7.centos..x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/armscii8.xml ... (same)
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ascii.xml ...
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1250.xml ...
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1251.xml ...
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1256.xml ...
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1257.xml ...
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp850.xml ...
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp852.xml ...
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp866.xml ...
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/dec8.xml ...
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/geostd8.xml ...
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/greek.xml ...
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/hebrew.xml ...
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/hp8.xml ...
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/keybcs2.xml ...
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/koi8r.xml ...
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/koi8u.xml ...
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/latin1.xml ...
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/latin2.xml ...
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/latin5.xml ...
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/latin7.xml ...
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/macce.xml ...
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/macroman.xml ...
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/swe7.xml ...

Error Summary
-------------
```

Problem is that mariadb is not installed. I uninstalled it. Even tried rebooting server to no avail. `yum package list` does not show either mysql or mariadb to be installed.

```
# yum remove -y mariadb
No match for argument: mariadb
No packages marked for removal.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!

# rpm -e mariadb
error: package mariadb is not installed

# rpm -V mariadb
package mariadb is not installed

# yum remove mysql -y
No match for argument: mysql
No packages marked for removal.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!

# yum remove mysql-common
No match for argument: mysql-common
No packages marked for removal.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!

# package-cleanup --cleandupes
Last metadata expiration check: 0:07:50 ago on Sat 23 Nov 2019 02:12:39 PM EST.
Error: No duplicated packages found for removal.

# dnf clean packages
0 files removed

# yum list installed | grep mariadb
#

# yum list installed | grep mysql
#
```

as you see there's nothing there. Even rebooted. Tried installing again same error as above.

Here is my full package list:

```
~# yum list installed
Installed Packages
NetworkManager..x86_64      
NetworkManager-libnm..x86_64        
NetworkManager-team..x86_64     
NetworkManager-tui..x86_64      
PackageKit..x86_64      
PackageKit-glib..x86_64     
acl..x86_64     
adcli..x86_64       
apr..x86_64     
apr-util..x86_64        
at..x86_64      
attr..x86_64        
audit..x86_64       
audit-libs..x86_64      
authselect..x86_64      
authselect-compat..x86_64       
authselect-libs..x86_64     
avahi-libs..x86_64
basesystem.noarch11-5.el8
bash..x86_64
bash-completion.noarch   1:2.7-5.el8 
bc..x86_64      
bind-export-libs..x86_64        
bind-libs..x86_64       
bind-libs-lite..x86_64
bind-license.noarch  32:9.11.4-17.P2.el8_0.1  @AppStream
bind-utils..x86_64      
binutils..x86_64        
biosdevname..x86_64     
blktrace..x86_64        
bpftool..x86_64     
brotli..x86_64      
bzip2..x86_64       
bzip2-libs..x86_64      
c-ares..x86_64
ca-certificates.noarch   2018.2.24-6.el8 
cairo..x86_64       
cairo-gobject..x86_64       
centos-logos..x86_64        
centos-release..x86_64      
checkpolicy..x86_64     
chkconfig..x86_64       
chrony..x86_64      
cockpit..x86_64     
cockpit-bridge..x86_64
cockpit-packagekit.noarch184.1-1.el8 
cockpit-system.noarch185.1-1.el8_0 
cockpit-ws..x86_64      
compat-openssl10..x86_64        
coreutils..x86_64       
coreutils-common..x86_64        
cpio..x86_64        
cracklib..x86_64        
cracklib-dicts..x86_64      
cronie..x86_64      
cronie-anacron..x86_64
crontabs.noarc
crypto-policies.noarch
cryptsetup..x86_64      
cryptsetup-libs..x86_64     
cups-libs..x86_64       
curl..x86_64        
cwp-httpd..x86_64       
cwp-suphp..x86_64       
cyrus-sasl-gssapi..x86_64       
cyrus-sasl-lib..x86_64      
cyrus-sasl-plain..x86_64        
dbus..x86_64
dbus-common.noarch   1:1.12.8-7.el8  
dbus-daemon..x86_64     
dbus-glib..x86_64       
dbus-libs..x86_64       
dbus-tools..x86_64
dejavu-fonts-common.noarch   2.35-6.el8   
dejavu-sans-fonts.noarch 2.35-6.el8  
desktop-file-utils..x86_64      
device-mapper..x86_64       
device-mapper-event..x86_64     
device-mapper-event-libs..x86_64        
device-mapper-libs..x86_64      
device-mapper-persistent-data..x86_64       
dhcp-client..x86_64
dhcp-common.noarch   12:4.3.6-30.el8 
dhcp-libs..x86_64       
diffutils..x86_64       
dmidecode..x86_64
dnf.noarch
dnf-data.noarch
dnf-plugin-spacewalk.noarch
dnf-plugins-core.noarch
dnf-utils.noarch
dos2unix..x86_64        
dosfstools..x86_64      
dracut..x86_64      
dracut-config-rescue..x86_64        
dracut-network..x86_64      
dracut-squash..x86_64       
dwz..x86_64     
e2fsprogs..x86_64       
e2fsprogs-libs..x86_64      
ed..x86_64
efi-srpm-macros.noarch   3-2.el8 
elfutils-default-yama-scope.noarch   0.174-6.el8 
elfutils-libelf..x86_64     
elfutils-libs..x86_64
emacs-filesystem.noarch  1:26.1-5.el8 
epel-release.noarch  8-7.el8  @epel
ethtool..x86_64     
expat..x86_64       
file..x86_64        
file-libs..x86_64       
filesystem..x86_64      
findutils..x86_64       
fipscheck..x86_64       
fipscheck-lib..x86_64
firewalld.noarch
firewalld-filesystem.noarch
fontconfig..x86_64
fontpackages-filesystem.noarch
fprintd..x86_64     
fprintd-pam..x86_64     
freetype..x86_64        
fuse-libs..x86_64       
gawk..x86_64        
gdbm..x86_64        
gdbm-libs..x86_64       
gdk-pixbuf2..x86_64
geolite2-city.noarch 20180605-1.el8  
geolite2-country.noarch  20180605-1.el8 
gettext..x86_64     
gettext-libs..x86_64
ghc-srpm-macros.noarch   1.4.2-7.el8
glib-networking..x86_64     
glib2..x86_64       
glibc..x86_64       
glibc-common..x86_64        
glibc-langpack-en..x86_64       
gmp..x86_64     
gnupg2..x86_64      
gnupg2-smime..x86_64        
gnutls..x86_64
go-srpm-macros.noarch2-16.el8
gobject-introspection..x86_64       
gpgme..x86_64       
gpm-libs..x86_64        
grep..x86_64        
groff-base..x86_64
grub2-common.noarch
grub2-pc..x86_64
grub2-pc-modules.noarch
grub2-tools..x86_64     
grub2-tools-efi..x86_64     
grub2-tools-extra..x86_64       
grub2-tools-minimal..x86_64     
grubby..x86_64      
gsettings-desktop-schemas..x86_64       
gzip..x86_64        
hardlink..x86_64        
hdparm..x86_64      
hostname..x86_64
hwdata.noarch0.314-8.0.el8
ima-evm-utils..x86_64       
info..x86_64        
initscripts..x86_64
insights-client.noarch   3.0.5-4.el8
ipcalc..x86_64      
iproute..x86_64     
iprutils..x86_64        
ipset..x86_64       
ipset-libs..x86_64      
iptables..x86_64        
iptables-ebtables..x86_64       
iptables-libs..x86_64       
iptstate..x86_64        
iputils..x86_64     
irqbalance..x86_64
iwl100-firmware.noarch  
iwl1000-firmware.noarch 
iwl105-firmware.noarch
iwl135-firmware.noarch 
iwl2000-firmware.noarch  18.168.6.1-92.el8.1  @anaconda
iwl2030-firmware.noarch  18.168.6.1-92.el8.1  @anaconda
iwl3160-firmware.noarch  1:25.30.13.0-92.el8.1@anaconda
iwl3945-firmware.noarch  15.32.2.9-92.el8.1   @anaconda
iwl4965-firmware.noarch  228.61.2.24-92.el8.1 @anaconda
iwl5000-firmware.noarch  8.83.5.1_1-92.el8.1  @anaconda
iwl5150-firmware.noarch  8.24.2.2-92.el8.1
iwl6000-firmware.noarch  9.221.4.1-92.el8.1   @anaconda
iwl6000g2a-firmware.noarch   18.168.6.1-92.el8.1  @anaconda
iwl6050-firmware.noarch  41.28.5.1-92.el8.1   @anaconda
iwl7260-firmware.noarch  1:25.30.13.0-92.el8.1@anaconda
jansson..x86_64     
json-c..x86_64      
json-glib..x86_64       
kbd..x86_64
kbd-legacy.noarch2.0.4-8.el8  
kbd-misc.noarch  2.0.4-8.el8 
kernel..x86_64      
kernel..x86_64      
kernel-core..x86_64     
kernel-core..x86_64     
kernel-modules..x86_64      
kernel-modules..x86_64      
kernel-tools..x86_64        
kernel-tools-libs..x86_64       
kexec-tools..x86_64     
keyutils-libs..x86_64       
kmod..x86_64        
kmod-kvdo..x86_64       
kmod-libs..x86_64       
kpartx..x86_64
kpatch.noarch0.6.1-1.el8 
krb5-libs..x86_64
langpacks-en.noarch  1.0-12.el8 
ledmon..x86_64      
less..x86_64        
libX11..x86_64
libX11-common.noarch 1.6.7-1.el8
libXau..x86_64      
libXext..x86_64     
libXrender..x86_64      
libacl..x86_64      
libaio..x86_64      
libappstream-glib..x86_64       
libarchive..x86_64      
libassuan..x86_64       
libattr..x86_64     
libbasicobjects..x86_64     
libblkid..x86_64        
libcap..x86_64      
libcap-ng..x86_64       
libcollection..x86_64       
libcom_err..x86_64      
libcomps..x86_64        
libconfig..x86_64       
libcroco..x86_64        
libcurl..x86_64     
libdaemon..x86_64       
libdb..x86_64       
libdb-utils..x86_64     
libdhash..x86_64        
libdnf..x86_64      
libedit..x86_64     
libestr..x86_64     
libevent..x86_64        
libfastjson..x86_64     
libfdisk..x86_64        
libffi..x86_64      
libfprint..x86_64       
libgcc..x86_64      
libgcrypt..x86_64       
libgomp..x86_64     
libgpg-error..x86_64        
libgudev..x86_64        
libidn2..x86_64     
libini_config..x86_64       
libipa_hbac..x86_64     
libkcapi..x86_64        
libkcapi-hmaccalc..x86_64       
libksba..x86_64     
libldb..x86_64      
libmaxminddb..x86_64        
libmetalink..x86_64     
libmnl..x86_64      
libmodman..x86_64       
libmodulemd1..x86_64        
libmount..x86_64        
libndp..x86_64      
libnetfilter_conntrack..x86_64      
libnfnetlink..x86_64        
libnfsidmap..x86_64     
libnftnl..x86_64        
libnghttp2..x86_64      
libnl3..x86_64      
libnl3-cli..x86_64      
libnsl2..x86_64     
libpath_utils..x86_64       
libpcap..x86_64     
libpipeline..x86_64     
libpkgconf..x86_64      
libpng..x86_64      
libpq..x86_64       
libproxy..x86_64        
libpsl..x86_64      
libpwquality..x86_64        
libref_array..x86_64        
librelp..x86_64     
librepo..x86_64     
libreport-filesystem..x86_64        
libseccomp..x86_64      
libsecret..x86_64       
libselinux..x86_64      
libselinux-utils..x86_64        
libsemanage..x86_64     
libsepol..x86_64        
libsigsegv..x86_64      
libsmartcols..x86_64        
libsmbclient..x86_64        
libsolv..x86_64     
libsoup..x86_64     
libss..x86_64       
libssh..x86_64      
libsss_autofs..x86_64       
libsss_certmap..x86_64      
libsss_idmap..x86_64        
libsss_nss_idmap..x86_64        
libsss_sudo..x86_64     
libstdc++..x86_64       
libstemmer..x86_64      
libstoragemgmt..x86_64      
libsysfs..x86_64        
libtalloc..x86_64       
libtasn1..x86_64        
libtdb..x86_64      
libteam..x86_64     
libtevent..x86_64       
libtirpc..x86_64        
libunistring..x86_64        
libusbx..x86_64     
libuser..x86_64     
libutempter..x86_64     
libuuid..x86_64     
libverto..x86_64        
libwbclient..x86_64     
libxcb..x86_64      
libxcrypt..x86_64       
libxkbcommon..x86_64        
libxml2..x86_64     
libyaml..x86_64
linux-firmware.noarch20190111-92.gitd9fb2ee6.el8  @anaconda
logrotate..x86_64       
lshw..x86_64        
lsof..x86_64        
lsscsi..x86_64      
lua-libs..x86_64        
lvm2..x86_64        
lvm2-libs..x86_64       
lz4-libs..x86_64        
lzo..x86_64
mailcap.noarch   2.1.48-3.el8
make..x86_64        
man-db..x86_64      
man-pages..x86_64       
mcelog..x86_64      
mdadm..x86_64       
microcode_ctl..x86_64       
mlocate..x86_64     
mozjs52..x86_64     
mpfr..x86_64        
mtr..x86_64     
nano..x86_64        
ncurses..x86_64
ncurses-base.noarch  6.1-7.20180224.el8   @anaconda
ncurses-libs..x86_64        
net-tools..x86_64       
nettle..x86_64      
newt..x86_64        
nftables..x86_64        
nmap-ncat..x86_64       
npth..x86_64        
nspr..x86_64        
nss..x86_64     
nss-softokn..x86_64     
nss-softokn-freebl..x86_64      
nss-sysinit..x86_64     
nss-util..x86_64        
numactl-libs..x86_64
ocaml-srpm-macros.noarch 5-4.el8 
openblas-srpm-macros.noarch  2-2.el8
openldap..x86_64        
openssh..x86_64     
openssh-clients..x86_64     
openssh-server..x86_64      
openssl..x86_64     
openssl-libs..x86_64        
openssl-pkcs11..x86_64      
os-prober..x86_64       
p11-kit..x86_64     
p11-kit-trust..x86_64       
p7zip..x86_64       
p7zip-plugins..x86_64       
pam..x86_64     
parted..x86_64      
passwd..x86_64      
pciutils..x86_64        
pciutils-libs..x86_64       
pcre..x86_64        
pcre2..x86_64       
perl..x86_64
perl-Algorithm-Diff.noarch   1.1903-9.el8
perl-Archive-Tar.noarch  2.30-1.el8  
perl-Archive-Zip.noarch  1.60-3.el8  
perl-Attribute-Handlers.noarch   0.99-416.el8
perl-B-Debug.noarch  1.26-2.el8  
perl-CPAN.noarch 2.18-397.el8
perl-CPAN-Meta.noarch2.150010-396.el8
perl-CPAN-Meta-Requirements.noarch   2.140-396.el8   
perl-CPAN-Meta-YAML.noarch   0.018-397.el8   
perl-Carp.noarch 1.42-396.el8  
perl-Compress-Bzip2..x86_64     
perl-Compress-Raw-Bzip2..x86_64     
perl-Compress-Raw-Zlib..x86_64
perl-Config-Perl-V.noarch0.30-1.el8 
perl-DB_File..x86_64        
perl-Data-Dumper..x86_64
perl-Data-OptList.noarch 0.110-6.el8 
perl-Data-Section.noarch 0.200007-3.el8 
perl-Devel-PPPort..x86_64       
perl-Devel-Peek..x86_64
perl-Devel-SelfStubber.noarch1.06-416.el8
perl-Devel-Size..x86_64
perl-Digest.noarch   1.17-395.el8
perl-Digest-MD5..x86_64     
perl-Digest-SHA..x86_64     
perl-Encode..x86_64
perl-Encode-Locale.noarch1.05-9.el8 
perl-Encode-devel..x86_64
perl-Env.noarch  1.04-395.el8
perl-Errno..x86_64
perl-Exporter.noarch 5.72-396.el8   
perl-ExtUtils-CBuilder.noarch1:0.280230-2.el8
perl-ExtUtils-Command.noarch 1:7.34-1.el8
perl-ExtUtils-Embed.noarch   1.34-416.el8
perl-ExtUtils-Install.noarch 2.14-4.el8  
perl-ExtUtils-MM-Utils.noarch1:7.34-1.el8
perl-ExtUtils-MakeMaker.noarch   1:7.34-1.el8
perl-ExtUtils-Manifest.noarch1.70-395.el8
perl-ExtUtils-Miniperl.noarch1.06-416.el8
perl-ExtUtils-ParseXS.noarch 1:3.35-2.el8
perl-File-Fetch.noarch   0.56-2.el8  
perl-File-HomeDir.noarch 1.002-4.el8 
perl-File-Path.noarch2.15-2.el8 
perl-File-Temp.noarch0.230.600-1.el8
perl-File-Which.noarch   1.22-2.el8 
perl-Filter..x86_64
perl-Filter-Simple.noarch0.94-2.el8  
perl-Getopt-Long.noarch  1:2.50-4.el8   
perl-HTTP-Tiny.noarch0.074-1.el8
perl-IO..x86_64
perl-IO-Compress.noarch  2.081-1.el8 
perl-IO-Socket-IP.noarch 0.39-5.el8  
perl-IO-Socket-SSL.noarch2.060-2.el8 
perl-IO-Zlib.noarch  1:1.10-416.el8  
perl-IPC-Cmd.noarch  2:1.02-1.el8
perl-IPC-SysV..x86_64
perl-IPC-System-Simple.noarch1.25-17.el8 
perl-JSON-PP.noarch  1:2.97.001-3.el8
perl-Locale-Codes.noarch 3.57-1.el8  
perl-Locale-Maketext.noarch  1.28-396.el8
perl-Locale-Maketext-Simple.noarch   1:0.21-416.el8 
perl-MIME-Base64..x86_64
perl-MRO-Compat.noarch   0.13-4.el8  
perl-Math-BigInt.noarch  1:1.9998.11-5.el8 
perl-Math-BigInt-FastCalc..x86_64
perl-Math-BigRat.noarch  0.2614-1.el8
perl-Math-Complex.noarch 1.59-416.el8   
perl-Memoize.noarch  1.03-416.el8
perl-Module-Build.noarch 2:0.42.24-5.el8 
perl-Module-CoreList.noarch  1:5.20181130-1.el8
perl-Module-CoreList-tools.noarch1:5.20181130-1.el8
perl-Module-Load.noarch  1:0.32-395.el8  
perl-Module-Load-Conditional.noarch  0.68-395.el8
perl-Module-Loaded.noarch1:0.08-416.el8  
perl-Module-Metadata.noarch  1.000033-395.el8
perl-Mozilla-CA.noarch   20160104-7.el8  
perl-Net-Ping.noarch 2.55-416.el8
perl-Net-SSLeay..x86_64
perl-Package-Generator.noarch1.106-11.el8
perl-Params-Check.noarch 1:0.38-395.el8 
perl-Params-Util..x86_64        
perl-PathTools..x86_64
perl-Perl-OSType.noarch  1.010-396.el8   
perl-PerlIO-via-QuotedPrint.noarch   0.08-395.el8
perl-Pod-Checker.noarch  4:1.73-395.el8  
perl-Pod-Escapes.noarch  1:1.07-395.el8 
perl-Pod-Html.noarch 1.22.02-416.el8 
perl-Pod-Parser.noarch   1.63-396.el8
perl-Pod-Perldoc.noarch  3.28-396.el8   
perl-Pod-Simple.noarch   1:3.35-395.el8 
perl-Pod-Usage.noarch4:1.69-395.el8
perl-Scalar-List-Utils..x86_64
perl-SelfLoader.noarch   1.23-416.el8
perl-Socket..x86_64
perl-Software-License.noarch 0.103013-2.el8 
perl-Storable..x86_64
perl-Sub-Exporter.noarch 0.987-15.el8
perl-Sub-Install.noarch  0.928-14.el8
perl-Sys-Syslog..x86_64
perl-Term-ANSIColor.noarch   4.06-396.el8   
perl-Term-Cap.noarch 1.17-395.el8  
perl-TermReadKey..x86_64
perl-Test.noarch 1.30-416.el8
perl-Test-Harness.noarch 1:3.42-1.el8
perl-Test-Simple.noarch  1:1.302135-1.el8
perl-Text-Balanced.noarch2.03-395.el8
perl-Text-Diff.noarch1.45-2.el8  
perl-Text-Glob.noarch0.11-4.el8  
perl-Text-ParseWords.noarch  3.30-395.el8   
perl-Text-Tabs+Wrap.noarch   2013.0523-395.el8  
perl-Text-Template.noarch1.51-1.el8  
perl-Thread-Queue.noarch 3.13-1.el8 
perl-Time-HiRes..x86_64
perl-Time-Local.noarch   1:1.280-1.el8 
perl-Time-Piece..x86_64
perl-URI.noarch  1.73-3.el8 
perl-Unicode-Collate..x86_64        
perl-Unicode-Normalize..x86_64
perl-autodie.noarch  2.29-396.el8
perl-bignum.noarch   0.49-2.el8  
perl-constant.noarch 1.33-396.el8  
perl-devel..x86_64      
perl-encoding..x86_64
perl-experimental.noarch 0.019-2.el8 
perl-inc-latest.noarch   2:0.500-9.el8  
perl-interpreter..x86_64
perl-libnet.noarch   3.11-3.el8  
perl-libnetcfg.noarch4:5.26.3-416.el8
perl-libs..x86_64
perl-local-lib.noarch2.000024-2.el8 
perl-macros..x86_64
perl-open.noarch 1.11-416.el8
perl-parent.noarch   1:0.237-1.el8  
perl-perlfaq.noarch  5.20180605-1.el8
perl-podlators.noarch4.11-1.el8 
perl-srpm-macros.noarch  1-25.el8
perl-threads..x86_64        
perl-threads-shared..x86_64
perl-utils.noarch5.26.3-416.el8 
perl-version..x86_64        
pigz..x86_64        
pinentry..x86_64        
pinfo..x86_64       
pixman..x86_64      
pkgconf..x86_64
pkgconf-m4.noarch1.4.2-1.el8 
pkgconf-pkg-config..x86_64      
platform-python..x86_64
platform-python-pip.noarch   9.0.3-13.el8 
platform-python-setuptools.noarch39.2.0-4.el8
plymouth..x86_64        
plymouth-core-libs..x86_64      
plymouth-scripts..x86_64        
policycoreutils..x86_64
policycoreutils-python-utils.noarch  2.8-16.1.el8
polkit..x86_64      
polkit-libs..x86_64     
polkit-pkla-compat..x86_64      
popt..x86_64        
prefixdevname..x86_64       
procps-ng..x86_64       
psacct..x86_64
publicsuffix-list-dafsa.noarch   20180723-1.el8   
python-srpm-macros.noarch3-37.el8
python3-asn1crypto.noarch0.24.0-3.el8
python3-audit..x86_64
python3-bind.noarch  32:9.11.4-17.P2.el8_0.1  @AppStream
python3-cairo..x86_64       
python3-cffi..x86_64
python3-chardet.noarch   3.0.4-7.el8  
python3-configobj.noarch 5.0.6-11.el8
python3-cryptography..x86_64
python3-dateutil.noarch  1:2.6.1-6.el8
python3-dbus..x86_64
python3-decorator.noarch 4.2.1-2.el8 
python3-dmidecode..x86_64
python3-dnf.noarch   4.0.9.2-5.el8
python3-dnf-plugin-spacewalk.noarch  2.8.5-11.module_el8.0.0+180+337688dc

python3-dnf-plugins-core.noarch  4.0.2.2-3.el8
python3-firewall.noarch  0.6.3-7.el8 
python3-gobject..x86_64     
python3-gobject-base..x86_64        
python3-gpg..x86_64     
python3-hawkey..x86_64
python3-hwdata.noarch2.3.6-3.el8 
python3-idna.noarch  2.5-5.el8
python3-iniparse.noarch  0.4-31.el8  
python3-libcomps..x86_64        
python3-libdnf..x86_64      
python3-librepo..x86_64     
python3-libs..x86_64        
python3-libselinux..x86_64      
python3-libsemanage..x86_64
python3-libstoragemgmt.noarch1.6.2-9.el8 
python3-libstoragemgmt-clibs..x86_64        
python3-libxml2..x86_64
python3-linux-procfs.noarch  0.6-6.el8
python3-magic.noarch 5.33-8.el8  
python3-netifaces..x86_64       
python3-newt..x86_64        
python3-perf..x86_64
python3-ply.noarch   3.9-7.el8
python3-policycoreutils.noarch   2.8-16.1.el8 
python3-pyOpenSSL.noarch 18.0.0-1.el8
python3-pycparser.noarch 2.14-14.el8  
python3-pyparsing.noarch 2.1.10-7.el8   
python3-pysocks.noarch   1.6.8-3.el8  
python3-pyudev.noarch0.21.0-7.el8
python3-pyyaml..x86_64
python3-requests.noarch  2.20.0-1.el8
python3-rhn-client-tools..x86_64

python3-rhnlib.noarch2.8.6-8.module_el8.0.0+180+337688dc

python3-rpm..x86_64
python3-rpm-macros.noarch3-37.el8
python3-schedutils..x86_64      
python3-setools..x86_64
python3-six.noarch   1.11.0-8.el8 
python3-slip.noarch  0.6.4-11.el8 
python3-slip-dbus.noarch 0.6.4-11.el8 
python3-sssdconfig.noarch2.0.0-43.el8_0.3  
python3-syspurpose..x86_64      
python3-systemd..x86_64     
python3-unbound..x86_64
python3-urllib3.noarch   1.23-5.el8   
qt5-srpm-macros.noarch   5.11.1-2.el8
quota..x86_64
quota-nls.noarch 1:4.04-10.el8
readline..x86_64        
realmd..x86_64
redhat-rpm-config.noarch 116-1.el8.0.1  
rhn-client-tools..x86_64

rng-tools..x86_64
rootfiles.noarch 8.1-22.el8  
rpm..x86_64     
rpm-build-libs..x86_64      
rpm-libs..x86_64        
rpm-plugin-selinux..x86_64      
rpm-plugin-systemd-inhibit..x86_64      
rsync..x86_64       
rsyslog..x86_64     
rsyslog-gnutls..x86_64      
rsyslog-gssapi..x86_64      
rsyslog-relp..x86_64
rust-srpm-macros.noarch  5-2.el8
samba-client-libs..x86_64
samba-common.noarch  4.9.1-8.el8 
samba-common-libs..x86_64       
screen..x86_64      
sed..x86_64
selinux-policy.noarch3.14.1-61.el8_0.2  
selinux-policy-targeted.noarch   3.14.1-61.el8_0.2  
setroubleshoot-plugins.noarch3.3.10-1.el8
setroubleshoot-server..x86_64
setup.noarch 2.12.2-2.el8  
sg3_utils..x86_64       
sg3_utils-libs..x86_64      
shadow-utils..x86_64        
shared-mime-info..x86_64        
slang..x86_64       
smartmontools..x86_64       
snappy..x86_64
sos.noarch   3.6-10.el8_0.3
sqlite..x86_64      
sqlite-libs..x86_64     
squashfs-tools..x86_64      
sscg..x86_64        
sssd..x86_64        
sssd-ad..x86_64     
sssd-client..x86_64     
sssd-common..x86_64     
sssd-common-pac..x86_64     
sssd-ipa..x86_64        
sssd-kcm..x86_64        
sssd-krb5..x86_64       
sssd-krb5-common..x86_64        
sssd-ldap..x86_64       
sssd-nfs-idmap..x86_64      
sssd-proxy..x86_64      
strace..x86_64      
sudo..x86_64        
symlinks..x86_64        
systemd..x86_64     
systemd-libs..x86_64        
systemd-pam..x86_64     
systemd-udev..x86_64        
systemtap-sdt-devel..x86_64     
tar..x86_64     
tcpdump..x86_64     
teamd..x86_64       
time..x86_64        
timedatex..x86_64       
tree..x86_64        
trousers..x86_64        
trousers-lib..x86_64
tuned.noarch 2.10.0-15.el8
tzdata.noarch2019a-1.el8 
unbound-libs..x86_64        
unzip..x86_64       
usbutils..x86_64        
util-linux..x86_64      
util-linux-user..x86_64     
vdo..x86_64     
vim-common..x86_64      
vim-enhanced..x86_64
vim-filesystem.noarch2:8.0.1763-10.el8
vim-minimal..x86_64     
virt-what..x86_64       
wget..x86_64        
which..x86_64
words.noarch 3.0-28.el8   
xdg-utils.noarch 1.1.2-5.el8
xfsdump..x86_64     
xfsprogs..x86_64
xkeyboard-config.noarch  2.24-3.el8 
xz..x86_64      
xz-libs..x86_64
yum.noarch   4.0.9.2-5.el8
zip..x86_64     
zlib..x86_64
```

Additionally mariadb-libs is NOT installed.

```
# yum remove mariadb-libs -y
No match for argument: mariadb-libs
No packages marked for removal.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

So removing maria-libs is not the solution unlike another question which proposes that.

Also tried to remove any extraneous files/folders.

```
rm -f /var/log/mariadb
rm -f /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log.rpmsave
rm -rf /var/lib/mysql 
rm -rf /usr/lib64/mysql 
rm -rf /usr/share/mysql
```

No luck. Same error like it exists even though it does not exist and it is not installed.

---

#### Last attempt: trying to install with mariadb reinstalled also fails

Lastly, I tried one more thing, which is to, after doing all this, then trying to **install mariadb** and then try installing mysql,

```
~# yum install mariadb -y
Last metadata expiration check: 0:02:02 ago on Sat 23 Nov 2019 02:51:37 PM EST.
Dependencies resolved.

...

Installed:
  mariadb-3:10.3.11-2.module_el8.0.0+35+6f2527ed.x86_64
  mariadb-common-3:10.3.11-2.module_el8.0.0+35+6f2527ed.x86_64
  mariadb-connector-c-3.0.7-1.el8.x86_64
  MariaDB-common-10.1.43-1.el7.centos.x86_64

Complete!
```

And mariadb installs fine, but mysql still doesn't install. It gives a different error, but this is because mariadb is installed in this case. If I remove mariadb again, it gives the original error again like above.

```
# yum install mysql -y
Last metadata expiration check: 0:02:18 ago on Sat 23 Nov 2019 02:51:37 PM EST.
Error:
 Problem: problem with installed package mariadb-3:10.3.11-2.module_el8.0.0+35+6f2527ed.x86_64
  - package mariadb-3:10.3.11-2.module_el8.0.0+35+6f2527ed.x86_64 conflicts with mysql provided by mysql-8.0.17-3.module_el8.0.0+181+899d6349.x86_64
  - package mysql-8.0.17-3.module_el8.0.0+181+899d6349.x86_64 conflicts with mariadb provided by mariadb-3:10.3.11-2.module_el8.0.0+35+6f2527ed.x86_64
  - conflicting requests
  - package MariaDB-client-10.1.40-1.el7.centos.x86_64 is excluded
  - package MariaDB-client-10.1.41-1.el7.centos.x86_64 is excluded
  - package MariaDB-client-10.1.43-1.el7.centos.x86_64 is excluded
(try to add '--allowerasing' to command line to replace conflicting packages or '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
#
```

I also tried the `--nobest` flag but that does nothing, and I tried the `--skip-broken` flag but then it installs nothing either since it thinks it's broken.

I also tried installing `mysql-server` but no luck on that either.

```
# yum install mysql-server
Last metadata expiration check: 0:04:49 ago on Sat 23 Nov 2019 02:51:37 PM EST.
Error:
 Problem: problem with installed package mariadb-3:10.3.11-2.module_el8.0.0+35+6f2527ed.x86_64
  - package mariadb-3:10.3.11-2.module_el8.0.0+35+6f2527ed.x86_64 conflicts with mysql provided by mysql-8.0.17-3.module_el8.0.0+181+899d6349.x86_64
  - package mysql-8.0.17-3.module_el8.0.0+181+899d6349.x86_64 conflicts with mariadb provided by mariadb-3:10.3.11-2.module_el8.0.0+35+6f2527ed.x86_64
  - package mysql-server-8.0.17-3.module_el8.0.0+181+899d6349.x86_64 requires mysql(x86-64), but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
  - package mysql-8.0.13-1.module_el8.0.0+41+ca30bab6.x86_64 is excluded
  - package MariaDB-client-10.1.40-1.el7.centos.x86_64 is excluded
  - package MariaDB-client-10.1.41-1.el7.centos.x86_64 is excluded
  - package MariaDB-client-10.1.43-1.el7.centos.x86_64 is excluded
#
```

Please help me solve this issue, thank you.

Comment: Seems pretty obvious right at the start. You tried to install mysql and yum wanted to install both mysql-common and MariaDB-common, which sounds like a packaging problem to me. Why not just use Maria? Regardless, this is not a programming question, and is off-topic for SO. Try [sf] or [su] instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the answer. Centos web panel wanted to install both so obviously doesn't have any problems with doing so, so unfortunately, you are incorrect as that is not the solution to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try install mysql-server instead using: yum install mysql-server

Comment: Just tried it and it gives the same error. Updated my question with the output.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are suffering from the issue caused by MariaDB bug for **InnoDB fails to start when fts table has FK relation** as reported here: [MDEV-20987](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-20987)

For quick relief from this problem, the only way to fix this issue is by downgrading the installation. Use following command to downgrade.

```
yum downgrade MariaDB-server MariaDB-common MariaDB-shared MariaDB-client MariaDB-compat MariaDB-devel
```

**NOTE:** Officially MariaDB has fixed the issue in the following unpublished versions:

```
10.1.43 [ 23703 ]
10.2.29 [ 23911 ]
10.3.20 [ 23909 ]
10.4.10 [ 23907 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

**MariaDB is a fork of MySQL, it supports the same features as MySQL**

try this command to install mariadb - **sudo yum install -y mariadb105-server.x86_64**

try this command to find available mariadb on yum if above version does not work- **yum list | grep -i maria**

then enable service - **sudo systemctl enable mariadb**

then start mysql - **systemctl start mariadb**

set config - **sudo mysql_secure_installation**

**This works for Amazon Linux ,hope it will work with centOS as well**